# How can this line be throwing a nil exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
order_items_info.pluck(:quantity_shipped).sum.abs
```

And I am getting this error in my log:

```
Error reindexing order 123456 - NoMethodError - undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

      inject(:+) || 0
      ^^^^^^
```

I cannot find any way to reproduce that error.
`order_items_info` is an array of hashes, but that doesn't matter. here is what I have tried:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 6.1.7)
irb(main):001:0> order_items_info = nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> order_items_info.pluck(:quantity_shipped).sum.abs
(irb):2:in `<main>': undefined method `pluck' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
irb(main):003:0> order_items_info = []
=> []
irb(main):004:0> order_items_info.pluck(:quantity_shipped).sum.abs
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> order_items_info = [{quantity_shipped: nil}]
=> [{:quantity_shipped=>nil}]
irb(main):006:0> order_items_info.pluck(:quantity_shipped).sum.abs
=> 0
irb(main):007:0> order_items_info = [nil]
=> [nil]
irb(main):008:0> order_items_info.pluck(:quantity_shipped).sum.abs
/home/deploy/zonmaster/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:157:in `block in pluck': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

      map { |element| element[key] }
                             ^^^^^
irb(main):009:0> order_items_info = [{quantity_shipped: 'abd'}]
=> [{:quantity_shipped=>"abd"}]
irb(main):010:0> order_items_info.pluck(:quantity_shipped).sum.abs
(irb):10:in `<main>': undefined method `abs' for "abd":String (NoMethodError)
```

But none of them give me an error on the `inject`.

Comment: Can you log value of `order_items_info`?

Comment: `[{"qty"=>1},{"qty"=>1}].pluck(:qty).sum`

Comment: @Alex it's not the same thing... `[{"qty"=>1},{"qty"=>1}].pluck(:qty) #=> [nil, nil]`

Comment: @phil it doesn't explain the error, but I suggest you provide an initial value for `sum` so `sum(0)`

Comment: In your irb session,  you are using Enumumerable's pluck method, but I am assuming in your Rails app you are using ActiveRecord's pluck method. I would suggest doing the actual query in the rails console and see why you get back for the query, then the pluck of the query result.

Comment: @LesNightingill i get the exact same error `[nil, nil].sum`

Comment: @nPn actually, no, it's not an ActiveRecord object. It is an Array of Hashes that we are constructing. We're looking for how an incorrect key could get into it.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your data contain `nil` value. You may want to exclude `nil` value from calculation:

```
order_items_info.pluck(:quantity_shipped).compact.sum.abs
```

About data from Alex's comment, I think the code fetch `qty` data wrongly.

```
[{"qty"=>1},{"qty"=>1}].pluck(:qty).sum
```

`pluck` in this case is a Enumerable method. https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/pluck

the data key is string but he pluck it by symbol, then it returns `nil` instead of value.

```
7.8 :017 > [{"qty"=>1},{"qty"=>1}].pluck(:qty)
=> [nil, nil]
2.7.8 :018 > [{"qty"=>1},{"qty"=>1}].pluck(:qty).sum
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):18
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)
```

We need to use string key: `"qty"`

```
2.7.8 :023 > [{"qty"=>1},{"qty"=>1}].pluck("qty")
 => [1, 1]
2.7.8 :024 > [{"qty"=>1},{"qty"=>1}].pluck("qty").sum
 => 2
2.7.8 :025 > [{"qty"=>1},{"qty"=>1}].pluck("qty").sum.abs
 => 2
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, asking for the wrong (it doesn't really matter about symbol or string) key results in nil (x the number of entries in the array). If I did a compact after the pluck that would hide the error. In our data it should not be possible that a key of a string is getting in there, so that is really the bug. Thanks again.

Comment: If you update the answer I will accept it. It is not about us having a key that is a symbol when it should be a string (or vice-versa). It is that the key we are asking for in the pluck is not in the hash, so we get a nil value back.

Comment: Thank you bro! I took an example data from Alex answer then my suggestion base on Alex example.
In your case, it's possible that your data contain `nil` value. You are correct!

Comment: that is a good solution